# creating custom controller and view error "Page Not found, No umbraco document matches the url '/home2/index'."

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I m new to Umbraco and doing some test / learning work.

I have created a new controller named Home2, please note I don't have a doc type for Home2. I want to create non Umbraco view/ pages that can work with Umbraco. On running I m getting below error:

[image]

Below is my code for Controller and view, please guide what I should do to create custom controllers and views that can work with Umbraco ? Do I need to create document type even for non Umbraco types ?

Controller:

namespace Web.Controllers
{
    public class Home2Controller : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController 
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

```
    public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
    {
        //Do some stuff here, then return the base method
        return base.Index(model);
    }

}
```

}

View:

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

### Index

Hello welcoem to our page....

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many people are confused about routing in umbraco, and this is a common question here on SO. Check out my latest answer: [Can I change URL of content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635768/can-i-change-url-of-content/25642486#25642486)

First you need to register your route when the app is starting. Create a new class which inherit from Umbraco.Core.ApplicationEventHandler. Then overwrite ApplicationStarted to add your rules. Like this:

```
protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
{
    //Custom route
    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
    "SomeName",
    "Something/{action}/{id}",
    new
    {
        controller = "MyController",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    });
}
```

Then create a controller which inherit from RenderMvcController (not a surface controller. Surface and Render controllers are used for 2 different things): http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/Templating/Mvc/surface-controllers)

```
public class MyController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController
{
    public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
    {
        //Do your db stuff here...
        return PartialView("~/Views/Partials/MyView.cshtml", model);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please guide a little more, looks my question is a little different from this reply. Thanks for your help.

Comment: sorry if my explanation is not clear. What I want to do is just add a custom controller and view in a MVC _ Nuget Umbraco CMS project and display some data coming from DB but not being managed from Umbraco back office.

Comment: @user576510 this is how you do it :) use example 2. Will give a longer explanation later today when I'm at my computer

Comment: kindly reply when you are available. Thx

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a custom page thats not handled within Umbraco you need to add it to the umbracoReservedUrls list which is found in your web.config eg

```
<add key="umbracoReservedUrls" value="~/config/splashes/booting.aspx,~/install/default.aspx,~/config/splashes/noNodes.aspx,~/Home2/Index" />
```

Comment: This is only for physic files/folders, and not routes

Comment: @TomMaton thanks, I did that but now I m getting 404 not found error. I m sorry to bother you further but can you please suggest me something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco takes care of all the routing so your page must exist within the content section of the back-office even if it's not umbraco related.  So you first create a document type and then a template for it. Once you've done that, you add the page in the content section.

You can then view that page (go to properties for the page in content, then click link to document).  At this point you can add a custom controller if you wish and it should derive from RenderMvcController or SurfaceController (if you do form posts)

Comment: Not correct. Pages can be outside umbraco's Content section with custom routes.

Comment: @IanS thanks. Appreciate your reply. Can you please guide what would be action for that page ? Will there be a difference in Render and Surface controllers ?